# How to change MySQL Port in Laragon?

Tags: mysql, windows, port, laragon

I am using Laragon and I need to change MySQL port from 3306 to some other value. I tried editing the port in `my.ini` but when I start Laragon again it goes back to 3306. I am using windows 11. Has anybody successfully did this? Can you please tell me how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Laragon control panel by clicking on the Laragon icon in the system tray.

Click on the "MySQL" button in the control panel.

In the MySQL settings window, you will see a field labeled "Port". Change this field to the desired port number.

Click on the "Apply" button to save the changes.

Restart the MySQL service by clicking on the "Stop" button, then the "Start" button.
You may also need to update your application's database configuration to use the new port number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I just needed to edit preferences -> Services & Ports -> specify the port number you want to assign to it. It is also necessary to edit the mysql default port in php.ini.